# Botón enviar Formulario que recibe los datos de 2 divisores

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, formularios, div

Estoy trabajando con `Laravel`, y para que el `formulario` no se hiciera muy pesado hacía abajo, decidí implementarlo en dos divisores dandole un `float left`y un `float right`para que se diversificara en el ancho de la página.

Bien mi problema es que creo que no recoge todos los datos:

```
    {!! Form::open(['route' => 'movimientos.store', 'method' => 'POST']) !!}
<div class="form-group">
    <div style="float:left; width:49%;">
        <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('codigo', 'Código') !!}
            {!! Form::text('codigo', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Código' , 'required']) !!}
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('hora', 'Hora') !!}
            {!! Form::input('hora', 'date', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Hora']); !!}
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('codigo_producto', 'Código del Producto') !!}
            {!! Form::text('codigo_producto', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Código del producto', 'required']) !!}
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('albaran', 'Albarán') !!}
            {!! Form::text('albaran', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Albaran' , 'required']) !!}
        </div>  
        <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('ubicacion', 'Ubicación') !!}
            {!! Form::text('ubicacion', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Ubicación' , 'required']) !!}
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('puo', 'PUO') !!}
            {!! Form::text('puo', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'PUO' , 'required']) !!}
        </div>         
    </div>

    <div style="float:right; width:49%;">

        <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('fecha', 'Fecha') !!}
            {!! Form::input('date', 'date', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Date']); !!}
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('tipo', 'Tipo') !!}
            {!! Form::text('tipo', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Tipo']) !!}
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('cantidad', 'Cantidad') !!}
            {!! Form::text('cantidad', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => '0, 10, 50 o 100', 'required']) !!}
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('acronimo', 'Acrónimo de Quień realiza el pedido') !!}
            {!! Form::text('acronimo', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'ALCA, MANC etc.']) !!}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
                {!! Form::label('codigo_ticket', 'Código del Ticket') !!}
                {!! Form::text('codigo_ticket', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Código del Ticket', 'required']) !!}
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
                {!! Form::label('codigo_proyecto', 'Código del Proyecto') !!}
                {!! Form::text('codigo_proyecto', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Código del proyecto']) !!}
        </div>               
    </div>
        {!! Form::submit('Registrar', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) !!}
</div> 
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Este es el `error`que indica:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'fecha' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `movimientos` (`codigo_producto`, `albaran`, `ubicacion`, `puo`, `tipo`, `cantidad`, `acronimo`, `codigo_ticket`, `codigo_proyecto`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (123, 1, DCM, 1, 1, 34, ALCA, 1, 1, 2017-09-04 09:51:46, 2017-09-04 09:51:46))

Si observo no recoge todo los datos que le deberían entrar en la `select`.

Comment: Por favor agrega el método del controlador que recibe la información y la almacena, además la migración y el modelo para entender un poco lo de tus tablas.

Comment: Sí está recolectando todos los datos. El error indica que estás intentando crear un registro en la tabla `movimientos`, pero no le estás estableciendo un valor al campo `fecha`.

Answer (score 0):

No tienes un campo llamado fecha en el formulario, suponiendo que almacenes directamente en la BD (con los nombres del formulario idénticos a los de la BD) y que el campo fecha de la bd está definido como NOT NULL.